# How to prove the function $f(T)=\sum_0^\infty a_n T^n$ is infinitely differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $\mathcal{L}(X)$ denote the Banach space of continuous linear endomorphisms $X\to X$. 
If the radius of convergence of $\sum_0^\infty a_n z^n$ is $\ge R$, then prove that $$f(T)=\sum_0^\infty a_n T^n$$is infinitely differentiable in $\{T\in\mathcal{L}(X):\|T\|<R\}$. Can someone tell me how to prove it?

Comment: why it is true?can someone give me a general idea how to know whether it is true ot not

Comment: When you say differentiable, you mean as a map between Banach spaces, right?

Comment: It;s not true as stated since you've only hypothesized that the radius of convergence of $\sum_0^\infty a_n z^n \ge R$; this says that there *may* be $R_1 < R$ larger than the actual radius of convergence of your series.  You might consider stipulating that the radius of convergence is *precisely* $R$.  Cheers!

Comment: Yes,it is between two Banach Space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $T:X\to X$ is a generic continuous linear endomorphism of a Banach space $X$. Call $Y:=\mathcal{L}(X)$ the Banach space of continuous
linear endomorphisms with the usual norm.

$f$ is continuous in any ball $B_{R'}(0)$ with $R'<R$ since it is expressed as a [normally convergent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence) series, so it is also continuous on $B_R(0)$.

Observe that the map $Y\to Y$, $T\mapsto T^n$ is infinitely differentiable for any $n$ and its $k$-th derivative at $T_0$ can be viewed as a multilinear map
$$ D^k T^n(T_0)[H_1,\dots,H_k]:Y^k\to Y $$
which equals
$$D^k T^n(T_0)[H_1,\dots,H_k]=\sum T_0^{j_0}H_{i_1}T_0^{j_1}H_{i_2}T_0^{j_2}\cdots H_{i_k}T_0^{j_k}$$
where the sum is over all permutations $(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ of $(1,\dots,k)$
and over all the nonnegative integers $j_0,\dots,j_k$ such that $j_0+\dots+j_k=n-k$. 
The simplest way to think about this is to consider all possible products of $n$ factors in which all of $H_1,\dots,H_k$ appear exactly once, while the remaining $n-k$ factors equal $T_0$. (If you didn't know this fact, check some example with small $n$ and $k$ to understand why it is true)

So the norm of $D^k T^n(T_0)$ (in the space $\underbrace{\mathcal{L}(Y,\mathcal{L}(Y,\cdots \mathcal{L}(Y}_{k\text{ times}},Y)\cdots))\cong\mathcal{L}^k(Y^k,Y)$, where the latter denotes the $k$-*multilinear* maps) is bounded by
$$\|D^k T^n(T_0)\|\le n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)\|T_0\|^{n-k}$$
if $k\le n$ (since the above sum has $n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)$ terms)
and vanishes if $k>n$.

So we know that (for any $k\ge 0$) the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n D^kT^n$ is normally convergent in any ball $B_{R'}(0)$ with $R'<R$, because $\sum_{n=0}^\infty
n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)|a_n|R'^n<\infty$ (why?).

To conclude it suffices to see that if $f_n:Z\to W$ are continuously differentiable functions between Banach spaces and $\sum_n \|f_n\|_\infty\le C$, $\sum_n \|Df_n\|_\infty\le C'$ (where the $\infty$-norm is over a fixed ball $B$ in $Z$) then $f:=\sum_n f_n$ is continuously differentiable with
$$Df=\sum_n Df_n.$$
(Then you just have to iterate this result choosing $Z=Y$ and $W=\mathcal{L}^k(Y^k,Y)$)
To show this we use the standard trick of subtracting our candidate differential before estimating:
choose any $z\in B$, $h\in Z$ (so small that $z+h\in B$) and observe that
$$\|f(z+h)-f(z)-\sum Df_n(z)[h]\|\le\sum\|f_n(z+h)-f_n(z)-Df_n(z)[h]\|.$$ 
Fix any $\epsilon>0$ and choose $N$ so that $\sum_{n>N}\|Df_n\|_\infty<\epsilon$. Now, by the mean value theorem,
$$\sum\|f_n(z+h)-f_n(z)-Df_n(z)[h]\|=\sum_{n=0}^N \|f_n(z+h)-f_n(z)-Df_n(z)[h]\|+\sum_{n>N}\|f_n(z+h)-f_n(z)-Df_n(z)[h]\|\le
o(\|h\|)+2\epsilon\|h\| $$
where we estimated the first sum with $o(\|h\|)$ thanks to the definition of differentiability. Since this holds for every $\epsilon$, we get
$$\|f(z+h)-f(z)-\sum Df_n(z)[h]\|=o(\|h\|),$$
which is our thesis.

Comment: Thanks for your help,this question was mentioned by my professor,but have no idea what it was. But now it is clear. Thanks